# Best way to auto-restore a database every hour

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I have a demo site where anyone can login and test a management interface.

Every hour I would like to flush all the data in the SQL 2008 Database and restore it from the original.

Red Gate Software has some awesome tools for this, however they are beyond my budget right now.

Could I simply make a backup copy of the database's data file, then have a c# console app that deletes it and copies over the original. Then I can have a windows schedule task to run the .exe every hour.

**It's simple and free... would this work?**

**I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Web edition**

*I understand that Red Gate Software is technically better because I can set it to analyze the db and only update the records that were altered, and the approach I have above is like a "sledge hammer".*

Comment: Not sure if your version supports this, but you can also look at snapshots. You can create a snapshot of your database and restore it regularly. The database needs to be in single user mode when you restore it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> > It's simple and free... would this work?

Yes, you could do it like that, just remember to put the DB in single user mode before restoring it otherwise your restore will fail

example script

```
USE master
GO

ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO



RESTORE DATABASE YourDB FROM DISK=N'D:\Backup\Pristine.BAK' WITH  FILE = 1,  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
GO

ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll just set a scheduled as a job in SQL to run this every hour. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be scripted using SQL and scheduled as a job on the server to execute once an hour.  Since you have a backup copy, I assume, that is pristine, then all you need to do is take the database offline, restore from the backup, bring the database back online.  All of this can be scripted.  Do you need the scripts?

Comment: Hi websch01ar, yes, please email them to me. Thanks
aron {at} uswebpro (period) com

Answer (score 0):

You could also detach the database, overwrite the data and log files from your template (previously detached) and then re-attach.

Comment: @aron It can be automated in the same way as a restore.  You could use a scheduled SSIS package, a script using xp_cmdshell, or an external Windows command script with sqlcmd for the SQL operations.